# How to solve `General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61` when install kafka

Tags: java, macos, gradle, apache-kafka

I'm trying to install kafka following the installation page from [kafka's official site](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart), and I encountered this error:

```
❯ cd kafka-3.0.0-src
❯ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.6'
❯ ./gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.6

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip
..............10%...............20%...............30%...............40%..............50%...............60%...............70%...............80%..............90%...............100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.1.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Faster incremental Java compilation
 - Easier source set configuration in the Kotlin DSL

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/user/Downloads/kafka-3.0.0-src/settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file '/Users/user/Downloads/kafka-3.0.0-src/settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)
       
 ...

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
```

I suspect this is because of my gradle version, but I have no idea how to solve it.

I'm using java 17 runtime:

```
❯ pwd
/Users/user
❯ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-39)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And the os is MacOS 11.6.2

Comment: You need a java 17 runtime to run class files with major version 61. I would look for a file that is compile with an older java version though.

Comment: @f1sh thanks for replying. Actually I'm using java 17 runtime, added to the question description. Thanks!

Comment: Given the stacktrace mentions `groovyjarjarasm.asm`, I guess the problem is that the shaded in ASM dependency of Groovy doesn't support Java 17. Try upgrading to a new version of Gradle (Java 17 support was experimental in Gradle 7.1.1), or if your project explicitly uses Groovy, see if using a newer version works.

Comment: You can try changing the version of Gradle from your IDE by going to Settings/Preferences > Gradle and entering a different version in the corresponding drop-down menu (I have seen on internet that they switch to the "Embedded" version of the JDK with this problem).

Comment: Why are you trying to compile Kafka source code? You do not need Gradle to install or run Kafka

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Gradle to install or run Kafka.

The page you linked to says to download a released tarball, not the sources. You could also `brew install kafka` (and Zookeeper) on a Mac, and use `brew services start` to run both.

Or you can use Docker